# Value being passed to function becomes 0

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to edit a byte in a specific memory address, but the offset is turned to 0 when it's passed to the function `write_byte()`.  If I hard coded the value, it works, but if I used `scanf()`, it doesn't work.

snippet of the code in main():

```
unsigned int offset, dumpsize;
char byte_data;    // 8-bit operation.
puts("Please input your memory's offset address (in HEX):");   
scanf("%x", &offset);    // input an offset address (in HEX) to write.                   
puts("Please input your BYTE data to be written:");   
scanf("%x", &byte_data);    // input data.
write_byte (mem, offset, byte_data);
```

My `write_byte()` function:

```
void write_byte(unsigned char *base_address, int offset, char byte_data){
    memcpy(base_address + offset, &byte_data, sizeof(char));
}
```

This is an example of it running:

```
The base address of your memory is: 7C9C4010h (HEX)
Please make a selection:
5
Please input your memory's offset address (in HEX, should be a multiply of 0x10h):
0
Please input the size of the memory to be dumped (between 256 and 1M ):
256

7C9C4010: 4C 93 F2 F4 1C B2 FA F3 07 AC 3A 3C 7A B8 39 89       ---     L . . . . . . . . . : < z . 9 . 
7C9C4020: 5A A8 EB 73 91 D5 9F 13 7D 38 05 61 03 70 B8 4F       ---     Z . . s . . . . } 8 . a . p . O 
7C9C4030: 83 AC 45 9F 5F BF 93 E6 6C 4D A2 66 85 DB EF DF       ---     . . E . _ . . . l M . f . . . . 
7C9C4040: 84 5B D3 16 B0 73 A9 AE AC AE 10 AF 1F C9 00 A2       ---     . [ . . . s . . . . . . . . . . 
7C9C4050: F5 C4 43 D4 84 56 BB 70 24 5F D6 29 3B 46 89 40       ---     . . C . . V . p $ _ . ) ; F . @ 
7C9C4060: A2 5D 56 D2 D0 00 81 FC 2E 12 2D 4D 5B AC F0 51       ---     . ] V . . . . . . . - M [ . . Q 
7C9C4070: 71 B3 A5 75 89 62 E5 2D 41 BC 57 7C 03 E0 BC 25       ---     q . . u . b . - A . W | . . . % 
7C9C4080: 3E 93 78 8E 13 F9 8C 42 8B 39 0F 66 E5 00 37 57       ---     > . x . . . . B . 9 . f . . 7 W 
7C9C4090: 33 DD CC BD BF B2 6A 01 EE C1 FC F1 A2 3A 97 60       ---     3 . . . . . j . . . . . . : . ` 
7C9C40A0: CD 10 EF 60 89 FB 22 95 B4 32 FB 9A B1 34 71 65       ---     . . . ` . . " . . 2 . . . 4 q e 
7C9C40B0: 12 3E A2 D1 70 0D D2 DE CF 4F 50 F1 89 E7 53 57       ---     . > . . p . . . . O P . . . S W 
7C9C40C0: 77 C2 38 02 3E D9 97 F2 8B 93 8D BD 47 7E 23 D8       ---     w . 8 . > . . . . . . . G ~ # . 
7C9C40D0: BC 45 AA AC 52 FC 8B A1 4D DB 14 D6 44 E6 AE BB       ---     . E . . R . . . M . . . D . . . 
7C9C40E0: 29 66 BD 67 40 D4 D9 4C E8 E6 0A 30 65 AC 0A A1       ---     ) f . g @ . . L . . . 0 e . . . 
7C9C40F0: F1 34 CD C3 B1 59 66 FE B4 F9 55 78 E0 83 35 0A       ---     . 4 . . . Y f . . . U x . . 5 . 
7C9C4100: E9 72 F0 AA C7 CA F6 B0 31 01 60 96 2D E9 B7 1F       ---     . r . . . . . . 1 . ` . - . . .

The base address of your memory is: 7C9C4010h (HEX)
Please make a selection:
1
Please input your memory's offset address (in HEX):
12
Please input your BYTE data to be written:
AD

The base address of your memory is: 7C9C4010h (HEX)
Please make a selection:
5
Please input your memory's offset address (in HEX, should be a multiply of 0x10h):
0
Please input the size of the memory to be dumped (between 256 and 1M ):
256

7C9C4010: AD 93 F2 F4 1C B2 FA F3 07 AC 3A 3C 7A B8 39 89       ---     . . . . . . . . . . : < z . 9 . 
7C9C4020: 5A A8 EB 73 91 D5 9F 13 7D 38 05 61 03 70 B8 4F       ---     Z . . s . . . . } 8 . a . p . O 
7C9C4030: 83 AC 45 9F 5F BF 93 E6 6C 4D A2 66 85 DB EF DF       ---     . . E . _ . . . l M . f . . . . 
7C9C4040: 84 5B D3 16 B0 73 A9 AE AC AE 10 AF 1F C9 00 A2       ---     . [ . . . s . . . . . . . . . . 
7C9C4050: F5 C4 43 D4 84 56 BB 70 24 5F D6 29 3B 46 89 40       ---     . . C . . V . p $ _ . ) ; F . @ 
7C9C4060: A2 5D 56 D2 D0 00 81 FC 2E 12 2D 4D 5B AC F0 51       ---     . ] V . . . . . . . - M [ . . Q 
7C9C4070: 71 B3 A5 75 89 62 E5 2D 41 BC 57 7C 03 E0 BC 25       ---     q . . u . b . - A . W | . . . % 
7C9C4080: 3E 93 78 8E 13 F9 8C 42 8B 39 0F 66 E5 00 37 57       ---     > . x . . . . B . 9 . f . . 7 W 
7C9C4090: 33 DD CC BD BF B2 6A 01 EE C1 FC F1 A2 3A 97 60       ---     3 . . . . . j . . . . . . : . ` 
7C9C40A0: CD 10 EF 60 89 FB 22 95 B4 32 FB 9A B1 34 71 65       ---     . . . ` . . " . . 2 . . . 4 q e 
7C9C40B0: 12 3E A2 D1 70 0D D2 DE CF 4F 50 F1 89 E7 53 57       ---     . > . . p . . . . O P . . . S W 
7C9C40C0: 77 C2 38 02 3E D9 97 F2 8B 93 8D BD 47 7E 23 D8       ---     w . 8 . > . . . . . . . G ~ # . 
7C9C40D0: BC 45 AA AC 52 FC 8B A1 4D DB 14 D6 44 E6 AE BB       ---     . E . . R . . . M . . . D . . . 
7C9C40E0: 29 66 BD 67 40 D4 D9 4C E8 E6 0A 30 65 AC 0A A1       ---     ) f . g @ . . L . . . 0 e . . . 
7C9C40F0: F1 34 CD C3 B1 59 66 FE B4 F9 55 78 E0 83 35 0A       ---     . 4 . . . Y f . . . U x . . 5 . 
7C9C4100: E9 72 F0 AA C7 CA F6 B0 31 01 60 96 2D E9 B7 1F       ---     . r . . . . . . 1 . ` . - . . .
```

AS you can see, the 0 offset is the one changing, not offset 0x12.

Edit: I ran gdb on it, and it seems that right after I enter the the `byte_data` value, offset value becomes 0.

```
The base address of your memory is: F7A7D010h (HEX)
Please make a selection:
1
Please input your memory's offset address (in HEX):
12
Please input your BYTE data to be written:

Breakpoint 3, setup_memory () at memory.c:175
175                         scanf("%x", &byte_data);    // input data.
(gdb) p offset
$3 = 18
(gdb) c
Continuing.
AD

Breakpoint 2, setup_memory () at memory.c:176
176                         write_byte (mem, offset, byte_data);  // write a byte to memory. 
(gdb) p offset
$4 = 0
```

Edit2: This is a **workaround** I decided to try out. I assigned the offset value to a global variable `unsigned int offset_g`.  It worked.  However, is it possible this is a GCC bug?

Comment: `scanf("%x", &byte_data);` the`%x` format specifier expects a pointer to an (unsigned) int, not to a char.

Comment: If your compiler isn't warning you about this, turn up the warning options (`-Wall -Wextra` is good for gcc and clang).

Comment: `char byte_data;` ==> `unsigned int byte_data;`

Comment: I'm seeing the warning (flag's enabled), but `byte_data`'s fine, though.  Only the offset value's being weird.

Comment: @wildplasser I provided a workaround.  Makes me think it's probably a bug.

Comment: Did you try @4386427's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435163/value-being-passed-to-function-becomes-0#comment97588296_55435163)?

Comment: Well, it's a bug in your code. You're lying to `scanf` about the types of your variables => undefined behavior.

Comment: Why is the offset value affected, and not the byte_data?

Comment: Please, don't use snippets of code.  Read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page and edit your question.